# Plotting Multiple Time Series In Multi-Panel Plot

Tags: r, plot, time-series, panel

I would like to compare river discharges from three different USGS stream gages using a multi-panel plot similar to the image below located here: 1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlYyg.png, where the x-axis is time, y-axis is river discharges (cfs), and each panel presents the hydrograph for each USGS gage. Below is the first ten rows of data and the subsequent code to create the plot, but without any luck. Any suggestions or solutions will be greatly appreciated.

```
> head(flow,n=10)
    DateTime USGS.1 USGS.2 USGS.3
1   1/1/2015   2220   4190   6980
2   1/2/2015   2180   4120   6660
3   1/3/2015   2690   4510   8110
4   1/4/2015   4550  12100  16800
5   1/5/2015   4660   9120  19400
6   1/6/2015   4350  10200  15300
7   1/7/2015   4010   6540  14400
8   1/8/2015   4020   7320  12800
9   1/9/2015   3760   7600  13000
10 1/10/2015   4160   7320  11900
> 
> flow$DateTime<-as.POSIXct(strptime(flow$DateTime,"%m/%d/%Y"))
> 
> flow.xts<-xts(flow,order.by=flow$DateTime)
> 
> plot(flow,screens=c(1,3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(ggplot2); library(tidyr)
df2 <- gather(df[-1], key = V2)
names(df2) <- LETTERS[1:3]
ggplot(df2, aes(x = A, y = C, group = B)) + geom_line() + facet_grid(B~.)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hello this is fairly easy with tidyr, dplyr and ggplot2

```
library(dlyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

flow %>% gather(Station, Q, USGS.1:USGS.3) %>%
mutate(DateTime=as.POSIXct(strptime(flow$DateTime,"%m/%d/%Y")) %>%
ggplot(aes(x=DateTime, y=Q)) +
   geom_point() +
   facet_wrap(~Station)
```

This is untested as you didn't provide a reproducible examples.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you are using `xts`? `zoo` is more flexible for time series without timezones.

```
library(zoo)
flow$DateTime<-as.Date(flow$DateTime,"%m/%d/%Y")
flow.zoo<-zoo(flow[,-1],order.by=flow$DateTime)
plot(flow.zoo, col=1:3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, P Lapointe. Your solution worked. I chose to use xts b/c I would like to also plot multipanels with DateTime as %m/%d/%Y %H:%M. Also, do you know how I could customize the axes of each panel and add a legend to each panel?

Comment: The argument `major.format` will format the x-axis labels. i.e. `plot.xts(flow,major.format="%m/%d/%Y% %H:%M")` . For labels for the horizontal and vertical axes use `xlab` and `ylab` .